# Suggestions for account merging across StackExchange network

Tags: support, migration, user-accounts

Questions or new users are often migrated to TeX.SX from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (SO). We try to support their account mergers via the [Text Building Blocks](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/430/5764):

#### Migrated questions/answers/users

- `[Welcome to TeX.sx!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.`
- `[Welcome to TeX.sx!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your answer was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer.`

  To make the comment more personal, you can replace `another stackexchange site` with the respective link, i.e. `[so]`, `[su]` or `[sf]` for the *big three* or `[something.se]` for everything else, e.g. `[ubuntu.se]`.

However, often times there is confusion and they end up creating a new (separate) account on TeX.SX from their original (say) SO account. If this is the case, how can we facilitate them to have their account merged or make suggestions as to achieve this?

Here is a hypothetical scenario: Assume UserX has an account with SO and the question is merged to TeX.SX. They create a new account UserY. Should we suggest UserY merges the TeX.SX account with SO and then flag it for moderator attention on SO to merge UserY with UserX? Would that solve the problem? Is not, what's the best way to make a suggestion?

Comment: I have to admit that when I first posted the question on SO and it got migrated I did not know what to do to merge the accounts.  I was also new to SO at the time. This was quite sometime ago so perhaps things have gotten better. Is there any reason why the account can't just be created automatically since all these sites are really the same within the same corporation so no information is given to a third party?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to amend your blurbs to specify that they should register with the same openid credentials as what they use on SO.

Of course, if they were unregistered on SO as well, they'd have to register there as well.

Comment: Thanks Anna. Taking @PeterGrill's comment into consideration, it may be that new users who are unfamiliar with the idea of registration across the network still register with different IDs. If this is the case, how would one go about consolidating these accounts? Also, what would be the difference between a registered/unregistered account? Does that have an impact on mergers?

Comment: @Werner Contacting a [community team member](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) should do. The main difference between an unregistered and a registered account is that the former is only tracked through cookies on the user's machine, so it's easy to lose ownership of it. A registered account has an OpenID associated with it (i.e. Facebook, Google, Stack Exchange, etc.). There's not much impact on mergers, so long as the user has at least one registered account. If not... give us a shout anyway and we'll fix it up. :)

Comment: How do "we give any of the community team members a shout"?

Comment: @Werner You can make a meta post, have a moderator ping one of us in chat, or send an email to the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of each page on the site.

Comment: Reminder: if the user is unregistered, cross-site association doesn't really work. Ask them to register - if they use the same credentials, everything should work automatically; if they don't, we can fix it.