# How to make an account?

Tags: support, new-users, user-accounts

How can I make an account?

The 
[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)
page suggests "please consider registering your account", without saying how.

If I start from
tex.stackexchange.com
the option "help" presents me with the "Help Center" page,
but even the "2-minute tour" does not say how to register.

From Google, I found
https://stackoverflow.com/help/creating-accounts
https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add
and the " Add a login using Google"
takes me to the "Top Questions" site

Comment: I wonder, how you could write this question at all, if you don't have an account ;-)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand it, the technique is to click on the "log in" link in the top bar:

[image]

Then log in using the same credentials you used on the source site (where you should have an existing account). This should automatically merge the two accounts (associate them with one another) and re-unite any migrated posts waiting.

If you don't have an account anywhere on the StackExchange network, click on "sign up" and follow the instructions.