# @SomeUser tag removed from comment

Tags: support

Occasionally, when I add a `@SomeUser:` to the beginning of my comments, they get removed when I commit the comment. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes, they are automatically removed if the user is already notified anyway, e.g. when it is the OP of the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes: it's been added to the StackExchange 'back end'  to keep comments tidy. From memory, it's only applied to comments addressed 'directly' to a question/answer.

Comment: Thanks. Is that a recent modification?

Comment: @Raphink: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation). NB, post may contain some amount of LOLcatz.

Answer (score 5):

> The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of
>   any new comment. There is no need to use @name to notify them. (You
>   may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the
>   author have been commenting on the post so far, the @name will be
>   automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no
>   value.)

([Answer to](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets-n/599#599) When writing a comment, how do I ensure that the person it is addressed to gets notified?, No. 10)

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed this, and was confused for a bit...I think that a yellow notice box is in order when this happens, so that the users can be informed that the comment was modified and yet the user **will** be notified.

Comment: I suppose you should make this a comment to the question, or better yet, a new question-feature request. You might want to check on [metase] if there a similar request already.