# '@OP' is always dropped by this site

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@SomeUser tag removed from comment](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/someuser-tag-removed-from-comment)

Please why does this site drop *@OP* in comments meant for 'OP'? If I write '@user01: ...', the part '@user01' is always dropped by the site. Can't the behaviour be made unpredictable?

Comment: This was introduced already quite a while ago. Because the OP is always notified the `@OP` is automatically removed. This is done by the stackexchange staff and we don't have no way to change that. This was heavily discussed on the Meta.Stackexchange.com and IIRC, is here to stay.