# How to use tex.se effectively (possible FAQ addition)

Tags: discussion

I made the following comment in chat, and it got 4 stars, so I thought I'd raise it on meta to see if we can construct some "How to use the site effectively" content for the FAQ.  (Which is only editable by the mods?)

> One thing I think the site is sorely
>   missing is some information on how to
>   use it effectively. For example, the
>   FAQ link doesn't do what many people
>   might expect it to do (compared to
>   e.g. a wiki). For example, I don't
>   think that many users know that a good
>   first place to look is in the tags and
>   that clicking on the FAQ link while
>   looking at the questions associated
>   with a tag is a good way to find
>   answers to common questions. This kind
>   of information should be somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The top part of the faq is editable by diamond moderators, feel free to escalate anything you feel is "must read" to that section.

Beyond that, if you feel there are changes to the /faq that would be beneficial to all network sites, we're open to that as well.

Comment: Where does the "top part" end (or the bottom part begin?)

Comment: How can the moderators edit it? I didn't found an 'edit' button yet.

Answer (score 1):

We've had a plan for a while to collect particular meta questions in to an "Unofficial FAQ" which, via the featured tag, would be linked on the main page.  A start on this has been made at: [What goes in the FAQ?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/86)

Hendrik and I had some discussion on this in some other question which I can't find right now ...

But it keeps getting put on the back burner!

---

**Edit**: I've just shifted it to the *front* burner:

[The Unofficial TeX-SX FAQ](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1144/86)

Comment: To get you started, [here's our discussion](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598/when-writing-a-comment-how-do-i-ensure-that-the-person-it-is-addressed-to-gets-n/618#618) `:-)`